# menu control resizing

Tags: c#, wpf, menu, resize

If my window gets re-sized, the menu control re-sizes with it. And it looks very nasty when that happens. How can I prevent this? I'm looking for a property called 're size' but there isn't any.

[Edit]

```
<Menu Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Name="menu1" Margin="0,0,0,384">
    <MenuItem Header="File" StaysOpenOnClick="True" FontFamily="Arial" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <MenuItem Click="Open_Click" IsEnabled="True">
            <MenuItem.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="Open" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </MenuItem.Header>
        </MenuItem>
    </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
```

[/Edit]

Comment: Please, add some code or at least more detail.  It's not even clear from your question what "menu control" refers to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because of `Margin` Property. Just remove it and set `VerticalAlignment="Top"` for **Menu**.

`Margin="0,0,0,384"` means that there are 384 units of length between **Menu** and bottom bound of Menu's visual parent. Thus it means that **Menu** height is dependent on it's visual parent height, which is dependent on window height in your case.

Specifying `VerticalAlignment="Top"` will lead to the following: **Menu** will be situated as high as possible in visual parent bounds and will have as small height as it possible to fit it's contents: "File" text in your case. If you think that's too small you can do 2 things: specify `Height` for **Menu** or, which is much more sensible, specify `Padding` for **Menu**. One would prefer specifying `Padding` because it will guarantee that **Menu** height will be enough to fit contents, no matter what FontSize or FontFamily etc. will be the **MenuItem** text.